# Magento 2.3 - How set custom options title by store view programmatically?

Tags: magento2.3, custom-options, translate, customizable-options

I would like to be able to translate the title of the customizable options.

The following code works correctly and adds the options in all store views. How to adapt it to have a translated title in each store view which would be like unchecking the "Use Default Value" box?

```
$opValues = [
        '0' => [
            'default_title' => 'Option 1',
            'title' => 'Option 1',
            'price' => '0',
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sku' => '',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'is_delete' => '0',
        ],

        '1' => [
            'default_title' => 'Option 2',
            'title' => 'Option 2',
            'price' => '0',
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sku' => '',
            'sort_order' => '1',
            'is_delete' => '0',
        ]
    ];

    $customOption = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');

    $customOption
        ->setTitle('Title')
        ->setType('radio')
        ->setIsRequire(false)
        ->setSortOrder(1)
        ->setPriceType('fixed')
        ->setValues($opValues)
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->save();

    $product->addOption($customOption);
```

[image: Magento custom options]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Same way all translations works using this

```
'title' => __('Option 1')
```

And writting the translation in the language file.

Comment: Hi !

I would like to be able to manage translations in the backend.
I would like to be able to replace the default value (uncheck the box) in the back-end but in programming.